# R - download de dados CVM via método POST (package httr)

Tags: r, httr

Estou tentando construir uma função em R para fazer o download múltiplo de documentos diretamente do sistema disponibilizado pela CVM.

As instruções gerais dadas pela CVM para o download múltiplo são descritas em: http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/Port/DownloadArqs/download02.htm

Em resumo, o acesso ao sistema depende de autenticação via login e senha e exige que se informem os parâmetros da consulta via método POST.
O sistema responderá em XML, disponibilizando as URLs para download dos documentos.

O que eu quero fazer é retornar no R a lista contendo essas URLs.
Para isso, tentei escrever uma função simples usando o package "httr", descrita a seguir:

```
sist_cvm <- "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/DOWNLOAD/SolicitaDownload.asp"

login <- list(txtLogin = "MEU_LOGIN", txtSenha = "MINHA_SENHA", txtData = "15/04/2015", txtHora = "00:00", txtDocumento = "4")

library(httr)

acesso <- POST(url=sist_cvm, body=login, encode="multipart", verbose())
```

Todavia, ao tentar rodar, retorna o seguinte erro:

> SSL certificate problem: Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)

Obs.: tentei fazer múltiplas combinações ao redigir a função `POST`, variando `encode` como `form`, `multipart` e `json`, bem como incluindo ou omitindo `verbose()`. Também tentei substituir os elementos de login e senha da lista `login` por `authenticate("MEU_LOGIN", "MINHA_SENHA")`. Em todos os casos, o mesmo erro foi retornado.

Alguém podia me dar alguma sugestão, por favor?

Obrigado!

Comment: Não dá pra testar sem usuário/senha, mas achei duas respostas ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557831/httr-package-ssl-certificate-error-ssl3-get-server-certificate), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411313/ssl-verification-causes-rcurl-and-httr-to-break-on-a-website-that-should-be-le)) no SOen que talvez te ajude. Basicamente, você precisa indicar um certificado válido para que a conexão com o servidor seja bem sucedida.

Comment: Caro Molx, ainda nao consegui... o máximo que obtive ao acrescentar "verifypeer = FALSE" foi retornar o mesmo resultado que se obtém ao tentar acessar o sistema de download múltiplo da CVM sem informar login e senha (mensagem de "login incorreto".

Comment: Mas tenho o WAMP instalado em meu PC e consigo fazer downloads múltiplos apenas da forma convencional (preenchimento manual) com o código HTML: 
<body>
<form method="post" action="https://WWW.RAD.CVM.GOV.BR/DOWNLOAD/SolicitaDownload.asp">
<p>Login: <input type="text" name="txtLogin" value="MEU_LOGIN">
<p>Senha: <input type="text" name="txtSenha" value="MINHA_SENHA">
<p>Data: <input type="text" name="txtData" value="13/03/2015">
<p>Hora: <input type="text" name="txtHora" value="00:00">
<p>Documento: <select name="txtDocumento">
<option value="DFP" selected="selected">DFP
</select></p>

Comment: Tente alterar o encode para "form" ao inves de "multipart", outra coisa é verificar se você está passando o certificado, conforme o link do post do Molx. 

cafile <- system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")

acesso <- POST(url=sist_cvm, body=login, encode="form", verbose(), config(cainfo = cafile))

Comment: Molx e Ícaro, agradeço pela tentativa de ajuda de vocês. Mas não deu mesmo. Pensarei em outra alternativa para automatização do download dos arquivos. O acesso via R trava mesmo na autenticação, infelizmente.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que na última versão do pacote httr esse problema está resolvido. Abaixo, um código que funcionou:

```
cvm <- "https://WWW.RAD.CVM.GOV.BR/DOWNLOAD/SolicitaDownload.asp"

informs <- list(txtLogin = "seulogin", 
          txtSenha = "suasenha", 
          txtData = format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%Y"), 
          txtHora = "00:00", 
          txtDocumento = "TODOS")

acesso <- POST(url = cvm, 
           body = informs, 
           encode = "form", 
           verbose())
```

Att.

Comment: Prezado João Henrique,Obrigado pela dica. No entanto, mesmo com ela não me foi possível ter êxito, pois surgiu uma nova mensagem de erro:

"Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates"

Em tempo: estou usando o package httr mais atual disponível.

Abs!

Comment: Tentei investigar, mas não sei como resolver esse problema por enquanto... Me desculpe!

Comment: Tente usar esse comando antes dos demais httr::set_config(config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ))

Comment: Prezado João, novamente agradeço pela dica, mas continua não funcionando. A mensagem agora foi: "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Couldn't connect to server"

Answer (score 1):

Para registro/histórico, segue exemplo de `form`, baseado na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58994/r-download-de-dados-cvm-via-m%C3%A9todo-post-package-httr#comment123020_58994) de [@tpiccarelli](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24015/tpiccarelli),  cujos dados retornam corretamente:

```html
<!-- http://www.cvm.gov.br/menu/regulados/companhias/download_multiplo/manual_tecnico.html -->
<body>
    <form method="post" action="http://seguro.bmfbovespa.com.br/rad/download/SolicitaDownload.asp">
        <p>Login: <input type="text" name="txtLogin" value="xxxxx"></p>
        <p>Senha: <input type="text" name="txtSenha" value="yyyyy"></p>
        <p>Data: <input type="text" name="txtData" value="26/04/2019"></p>
        <p>Hora: <input type="text" name="txtHora" value="00:00"></p>
        <p>Exibe Assunto IPE:
            <select name="txtAssuntoIPE">
                <option value="SIM" selected="selected">Sim</option>
                <option value="NÃO">Não</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>Documento:
            <select name="txtDocumento">
                <option value="TODOS" selected="selected">TODOS</option>
                <option value="DFP">DFP</option>
                <option value="ENET">ENET</option>
                <option value="FCA">FCA</option>
                <option value="FRE">FRE</option>
                <option value="IAN">IAN</option>
                <option value="IPE">IPE</option>
                <option value="ITR">ITR</option>
                <option value="RAD">RAD</option>
                <option value="SEC">SEC</option>
            </select>
            <table style="margin-top: 10px;font-size: 12px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Sigla</b></td>
                        <td><b>Tipo de documento</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>DFP</td>
                        <td>Demonstrações Fianceiras Padronizadas</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ENET</td>
                        <td>Programa Empresas.NET</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>FCA</td>
                        <td>Formulário Cadastral</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>FRE</td>
                        <td>Formulário de Referência</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>IAN</td>
                        <td>Informações Anuais</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>IPE</td>
                        <td>Informações Periódicas</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ITR</td>
                        <td>Informações Trimestrais</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>RAD</td>
                        <td>Formulários ITR, DFP e IAN</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>SEC</td>
                        <td>Formulário de Securitiza/td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Em tempo, para quem busca outras alternativas simples, segue trecho de código em `python` que retornaria o mesmo resultado.

```py
import requests

data = {
    'txtLogin': 'xxxxx', 
    'txtSenha': 'yyyyy', 
    'txtData': '26/04/2019', 
    'txtHora': '00:00', 
    'txtAssuntoIPE': 'SIM',
    'txtDocumento': 'TODOS',
}

url = 'http://seguro.bmfbovespa.com.br/rad/download/SolicitaDownload.asp'

r = requests.post( url = url, data = data )

for line in r.iter_lines():
    print( line )
```

Comment: O código em Python funcionou perfeitamente