# R - download de dados CVM via método POST (package httr) (novo - continua)

Tags: r, post, método, download

Boa tarde galera!! Eu gostaria de ter feito esta pergunta lá neste post, o qual faço referência no título, porém não foi possível.

O que acontece é o seguinte: Estou usando, para o mesmo fim, a resolução do nosso querido amigo Tpiccarelli (link: [R - download de dados CVM via método POST (package httr)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58994/r-download-de-dados-cvm-via-m%C3%A9todo-post-package-httr)).

A questão é, a única coisa que mudou foi o site (url para qual se manda o post), porém não consigo retornar a resposta correta.

O que recebo a seguinte mensagem: **"Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to connect to siteseguro.bovespa.com.br port 443: Connection refused"**

E a resposta que vem em XML é : **"[1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58994/r-download-de-dados-cvm-via-m%C3%A9todo-post-package-httr) "404 - File or directory not found.Server Error404 - File or directory not found.The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."**

Procurando saber o que possa ser, li que pode ser algum problema de proxy (novato aqui nem sabe o que é isso -.-) ou firewall... enfim. Alguém conseguiria dar uma luz??

abaixo segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
library(httr)
library(xml2)

cvm <- "https://siteseguro.bovespa.com.br/rad/download/SolicitaDownload.asp"

informs <- list(txtLogin = "Login", 
                txtSenha = "senha", 
                txtData = "data", 
                txtHora = "hora", 
                txtDocumento = "ITR")

acesso <- POST(url = cvm, 
               body =informs , 
               encode = "json", 
               verbose())


conteudo=(read_xml(acesso$content))

xml_text(conteudo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Street,

Voltou a funcionar fazendo-se o seguinte:

1 - Mudei de servidor, agora uso o "http://seguro.bmfbovespa.com.br/rad/download/SolicitaDownload.asp"

2 - Estou usando http em vez de https

Agora está perfeito o acesso!!!
Voltou a fazer o download múltiplo.

Abs
Eduardo

Comment: Valeu Eduardo funcionou aqui também! Aproveitando que você está na mesma que eu, gostaria de saber se voce tem uma i formação para me dar.

As informaçôes sobre o download múltiplo são muitos ruins, é dificil saber o que cada item significa. No InfoFinadFin, arquivo que contém os ITR, DFP , etc, o "ValorConta", por exemplo, extiste ValorConta 1, 2 ..., 12, você saberia dizer se há um padrão?exemplo: valor conta 2 é pro trimestre atual, mas no DFC por exemplo, o trimestre atual vem no ValorConta 4.
Será que existe um manual explicando o que significa cada informação? Abraços e obrigado!

Comment: Para resolver o problema ITR, DFP e Valor da Conta, fiz um mapa, em Excel, que relaciona todos esses detalhes. Poderia te mandar essa planilha.

Comment: seria show hein!! certamente tem muita gente procurando isso, voce poderia subir para um git também ! meu e-mail : street_prog@hotmail.com